# Why Terraform shows previous value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I see this happens when I am updating the user_data in ec2_instance. AWS EC2 instance gets recreated when user_data changes. The terraform output should print the new EC2 instance IP address, but it prints the old EC2 instance IP address. How can we solve this problem? Is it because Terraform tries to output the value before the EC2 address has the new IP address? I am running Terraform from GitHub actions if it is relevant. But I am using the latest terraform action for my project. hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2 and the terraform state is stored in AWS S3.

AWS credential setting is also done using the latest action: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2. I am using an IAM role in AWS which gets assigned to the GitHub Action through OIDC.

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  ami                    = "ami-053b0d53c279acc90" # Change this to the correct Ubuntu 20.04 AMI ID
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"              # Change to the desired instance type
  key_name               = "aws_keys_pairs-tfa"    # Change to your key pair name
  iam_instance_profile   = aws_iam_instance_profile.ec2_profile.name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ssh-sec-grp.id]
  
  tags = {
    Name = "Ubuntu-Docker-Instance=tfa"
  }
  
  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    host = self.public_ip
    user = "ubuntu"
        
    # Mention the exact private key name which will be generated 
    private_key = file("aws_keys_pairs.pem")
    timeout     = "4m"
  }
}    
    
output "ec2_public_ip" {
  description = "Public IP of the instance"
  value       = aws_instance.ec2_instance.*.public_ip
}
```

Output example:

```
> 2023-08-23T05:23:37.274Z [WARN]  Provider "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]" produced an unexpected new value for aws_instance.ec2_instance, but we are tolerating it because it is using the legacy plugin SDK.
    The following problems may be the cause of any confusing errors from downstream operations:
      - .public_ip: was cty.StringVal("54.152.128.106"), but now cty.StringVal("34.230.23.155")
      - .public_dns: was cty.StringVal("ec2-54-152-128-106.compute-1.amazonaws.com"), but now cty.StringVal("ec2-34-230-23-155.compute-1.amazonaws.com")
aws_instance.ec2_instance: Modifications complete after 1m1s [id=i-06225b4f29db7d3dc]
data.aws_instance.new_instance: Reading...
data.aws_instance.new_instance: Read complete after 1s [id=i-06225b4f29db7d3dc]
```

Outputs:

```
   ec2_public_ip = [
      "54.158.213.194",
    ]
```

Comment: Why are you using the '*' in the output's value?

Comment: "Is it because Terraform tries to output the value before the EC2 address has the new IP address?" - no, since that is an implicit dependency it will be availabe only **after** the resource is created.

Comment: Are you sure the IP address of the newly replaced instance is different from the old one?

Comment: @lxop added output example

Comment: At which point does this old IP output appear? Is it in response to a `terraform plan` call prior to the `apply` call, or is it at the very end of everything (i.e., comes from the `apply` call)?

Comment: @lxop after terraform apply.

Comment: Your "output example" seems to include a substring from a debug warning intended to help provider developers debug implementation errors in their providers, so I assume you're running Terraform with the internal developer logs enabled. Can you edit your question to show the entirety of that warning? It will hopefully give a clue as to when in the plan and apply process that apparent problem is occuring.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I added more content from the output. Please note that I am using latest provider for AWS in terraform